# Can 'Subject' field be filtered in Case Object

Tags: soql

[image]I am trying to filter 'Subject' field in Case Object using SOQL Query in the Where Caluse. But It says Subject can not be filtered in a Query cell.

eg: `Select xxx From Case Where Subject = 'XXX'`

Below is the error I receive when I run the SOQL query to filter Subject. It says it can't be filtered. Is there any alternate solution for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/58BUu.png

Appreciate the help

Thanks,
Sweta

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the exact error message text and your specific SOQL query text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Case field `Subject` can't available for `SOQL` filters. As per SFDC [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm), Field `Subject` can able to filterable.

You can use both sample queries,

`SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject FROM Case WHERE Subject = 'XXX';`

OR

`SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject FROM Case WHERE Subject LIKE '%XXX%';`

Both above queries are valid. So please check your query, Is there any issues in `SOQL` query formation.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I pasted a screenshot below. please check

Comment: @SwetaC Hi, Please help to add your screenshot clearly into your question by edit. Currently it's not visible

Comment: I just added the screenshot please check

Comment: Please check case field 'Subject' access for your profile. Minimum it's need to be read only access for using that field in soql query. OR Please login again into https://workbench.developerforce.com and try again to query (May be it's will be a cache's issue from Workbench)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. For now I am able to filter it through SubjectForSOQL__c

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it solved by my answer. Please accept that answer, which will help into new people in SFSE who having the same doubt in forward days. If it's not please post your answer which will help you in this case. Have a great Day!!